# BeautifulSoup & Craiglist - Trouble getting data with identical attributes and structure

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, craigslist

I am having trouble scraping the HTML below as all the info is stored in a structure that doesn't have very much distinction.

I want to get a place that retrieves the b tag contained within the span tag that has text = 'VIN:  ', and the b tag contained within the span tag that has text = 'odometer:  ', etc..

```
</p>
</div>
<p class="attrgroup">
<span><b>2001 PORSCHE 911</b></span>
<br/>
</p>
<p class="attrgroup">
<span>VIN: <b>WP0CA29961S653221</b></span>
<br/>
<span>fuel: <b>gas</b></span>
<br/>
<span>odometer: <b>46000</b></span>
<br/>
<span>paint color: <b>silver</b></span>
<br/>
<span>size: <b>sub-compact</b></span>
<br/>
<span>title status: <b>clean</b></span>
<br/>
<span>transmission: <b>manual</b></span>
<br/>
<span>type: <b>convertible</b></span>
<br/>
</p>
</div>
```

I have tried the following variations with no avail:

```
all = soup.find_all('section',{'class':'body'})
for i in all:
    print(i.find_all('span'))
```

&

```
all = soup.find_all('section',{'class':'body'})
for i in all:
     print(i.find_all('b'))
```

&

```
all = soup.find_all('section',{'class':'body'})
for i in all:
    print(i.find_all('p',{'class':'attrgroup'}))
```

The fields are dynamic, so the structure can change.  For example, another listing may not have the odometer information, or the fuel option, so breaking this into a list and getting specific information by index will not be consistent.

How do I successfully do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with some similar like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
</p>
</div>
<p class="attrgroup">
<span><b>2001 PORSCHE 911</b></span>
<br/>
</p>
<p class="attrgroup">
<span>VIN: <b>WP0CA29961S653221</b></span>
<br/>
<span>fuel: <b>gas</b></span>
<br/>
<span>odometer: <b>46000</b></span>
<br/>
<span>paint color: <b>silver</b></span>
<br/>
<span>size: <b>sub-compact</b></span>
<br/>
<span>title status: <b>clean</b></span>
<br/>
<span>transmission: <b>manual</b></span>
<br/>
<span>type: <b>convertible</b></span>
<br/>
</p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
prefixes = ["VIN", "odometer"]
for n in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'attrgroup'}):    
   for x in n.find_all('span'):
    if(x.text.startswith(tuple(prefixes))):
      print(x.find('b').text)
```

Result:

```
WP0CA29961S653221
46000
```